# frozen sourcetree pushing commit

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to push changes in my project but sourcetree is loading for hours but it does not work out. it´s not frozen but can´t push the changes.
[image: image output]

Comment: Did this ever resolve itself? I'm experiencing this on a specific repo. All others repo's OK, and other team members not having issues with the repo I am.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the repo in SourceTree to use SSH url rather than https. Try this (or switching to https if you're using SSH url)